# How to capture selection from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in the view:

```
<%= collection_select(:menu, :postnumer, @menus, :postnumer_id, :postnumer,
    options = {:prompt => "Veldu póstnúmer", :include_blank => "Ekkert valið"},
    html_options = {:class =>"menus", :multiple => true, :style => 'width:15%'}) %>
```

The selection menu displays correctly with the list of items from the model. But I have not been able to figure out how to collect the selected item.
Can anyone help?

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @menus = Menu.all
    end

    def result
        @results = params[menu][postnumer_id]
    end

 end
```

View:

```
<th>Póstnúmer:</th></br>
<%= collection_select(:menu, :postnumer, @menus, :postnumer_id, :postnumer, options =         {:prompt => "Veldu póstnúmer", :include_blank => "Ekkert valið"}, html_options = {:class =>"menus", :multiple => true, :style => 'width:15%'}) %></br>
<%= button_to "Hefja leit", {:controller => :menus, :action => :result}, {:method =>    :post} %>
```

Another day and I read the suggestion from Mischa where he pointed me to an excellent article on symbols.
That got me thinking on the use of symbols.
I have two models Menu and Rent, schema.rb below:

`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140403200844) do

```
create_table "menus", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "postnumer"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "postnumer_id"
end

create_table "rents", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "fastanumer"
    t.string   "postnumer"
    t.string   "gotuheiti"
    t.float    "flatarmal"
    t.float    "fermetraverd"
    t.float    "upr_fermetraverd"
    t.float    "verd"
    t.datetime "dagsetning"
    t.string   "sveitarfelagsnumer"
    t.integer  "byggingarar"
    t.integer  "fjoldiherbergja"
    t.string   "matssvaedi"
    t.string   "ist120"
    t.float    "visitala_start"
    t.float    "visitala_end"
    t.string   "undirmatssvaedi"
    t.float    "fasteignamat"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

end
`
I am using same symbols in both Menu and Rent. Can that cause problems?

I have changed the code based on the suggestions to this post and spent some days now on reading and focusing on the routes file. I am still not getting this to work. When I submit the form the result method is not being run and the value from the collection_select helper is not being picked up. I am wondering if anyone could help with some further suggestions? The code is as follows:
class MenusController < ApplicationController

```
def create
    @menus = Menu.all
end

def result
    @results = params[:menu][:postnumer_id]
end
```

end

View:
    <%= form_tag menus_path do %>
        
            <%= label_tag 'Póstnúmer:' %>
            <%= collection_select(:menu, :postnumer, @menus, :postnumer_id, :postnumer, options = {:prompt => "Veldu póstnúmer:"}, html_options = {:class => "menus", :multiple => true, :style => 'width:15%'}) %>
        
        
            <%= submit_tag "Hefja leit", :action => "result", :controller => "menus"%>

```
<% end %>  


Pricetorent::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :menus, :only => [:result]
    get "menus/create"
    post "menus/result"
    resources :menus do
        put :result, :on => :collection
    end
end
```

Comment: if you select one entry and submit the form, whats the param?

Comment: Maybe my initial question is wrong. I am not sure how to submit the form? There lies my problem.

Comment: Can you share the complete form code and the corresponding Controller action.

Comment: i think this link will help you http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html. But i suggest that you read some beginner tutorials like http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning

Comment: I have already read Apress.Beginning.Ruby. 

Almost finished with Beginning Rails 4.

Sorry for being sucha a newby.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
@results = params[menu][postnumer_id]
```

You should use:

```
@results = params[:menu][:postnumer_id]
```

`menu` and `postnumer_id` are variables (which are undefined) and `:menu` and `:postnumer_id` are symbols. You can read up on symbols in Ruby [here](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I had already tried it as a symbol but get error both way's.
When I select an entry in the list and press the button "Hefja leit"
I get the error: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"
This error is generated when the line in the controller is like this: `@results = params[:menu][:postnumer_id]`

Comment: @user3334207 That means `params` is `nil`. Is the `collection_select` in a form? It needs to be in a form. Then you submit the form and the contents of the form will be available in `params` in your controller. If you use `button_to` like that, your `collection_select` is not passed to the controller.

Comment: Thanks you Mischa. Can I use form_for and collection_select together? Do you have any suggestion for a good article on the form helpers in rails. The rails documentation is a bit confusing for a newbie. I really appreciate your help and open mind when it comes to a newbie.